# Зависимость пользователя и базы в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

У меня стоит PostgreSQL. Я создал новую базу `create database myBase`, и хотел перейти к ее редактированию. Но на всех ресурсах я вижу схему где для новой базы создают нового пользователя.

1. Могу ли я начать редактировать базу используя уже существующего? Как это сделать?
2. В чем вообще идея пользователя базы в PostgreSQL?
3. В чем заключается общий принцип зависимости пользователь-база в PostgreSQL?

Вот мой лог:

```
Last login: Wed Apr 19 19:35:57 on ttys000
Mac-mini-Pavel:~ pavel$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/scripts/runpsql.sh; exit
Server [localhost]: 
Database [postgres]: 
Port [5432]: 
Username [postgres]:  
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create database myBase;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 mybase    | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=#
```

Comment: Зависимости пользователя от базы и наоборот определяет администратор сервера, назначая пользователям привилегии. Курите мануалы: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/user-manag.html https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-priv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. да. в `psql` подключитесь к базе `\c mybase` или укажите базу при подключении: `psql mybase`
2. [Глава 21. Роли базы данных](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/user-manag.html)
3. [Права](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/ddl-priv.html)

спасибо Сергею за ссылки